# JavaScript - rotate a shape by a fixed angle

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to move a shape around the circumference of a circle on HTML canvas. I am using the following JavaScript logic:

```
speed = 0.005;
angle = Math.PI/2;
angle +=  speed * direction;
var x = cx + (radius * Math.cos(angle));
var y = cy + (radius * Math.sin(angle));
```

`direction` is set by a key press (left arrow = -1, right arrow = +1). `cx` and `cy` are fixed - they are the x and y co-ordinates of the center of the circle around which the shape is moving.

I want to move the shape around the circle in fixed steps, like the seconds hand of a clock. However, there should be 187 steps. I know that dividing 360/187 = 1.9251 degrees = 0.03359 radians. However, my drawing function is inside a loop, so writing `angle += 0.03359` makes the shape spin around the circle forever.

How can I make each key press move the shape either clockwise or anti-clockwise around the circle, but in steps of 0.3359 radians?

I am using the logic I found in the answer written by [rafaelcastrocouto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242389/rafaelcastrocouto?tab=profile) for this question: [how to move object in circle forward and backward in html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862954/how-to-move-object-in-circle-forward-and-backward-in-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the starting angle in avariable that you access each time you begin to draw:

This line:

```
angle = Math.PI/2;
```

should then look like this:

```
angle = window.starting_angle;
```

On each keypress, you either increment or decrement this variable and redraw the shape.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. :)